# Kendo UI Grid/DataSource - Global Error Handling?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've currently inherited an application which has numerous Kendo grids (and other controls) throughout, and I'm trying to fix an error which keeps cropping up now and again - specifically when the user is no longer authenticated.

I know what the solution is for a single instance of the control - return a flag to indicate authentication failed, and then detect this in the error handler and perform the authentication.

The problem is am I really going to have to handle this for every instance of a Kendo control I have? Is there not a global error handler I can hook into? Either for the data source itself (as I know this is used for all Kendo control data loading), or for the Grid specificially. I don't mind either way - just which one is a hook.

This would be a more straighforward short term solution than refactoring everything to specific error handlers, etc.

Comment: You say Global Error Handling for `DataSource`, for `Grid`, for `Kendo` controls,... It is not clear to me what is the actual requirement. Is it _enough_ for `DataSource`?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear in my question - I have updated it to be more explicit. I don't mind either way - the datasource level itself should be enough if such functionality is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you can attach a global error handler to $.ajax, which is used by the DataSource, you can check how to do it here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Or, you can take advanttage of that the configuration that is done in the DataSource is passed directly to the $.ajax:
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read-ObjectStringFunction

Comment: Thanks Botis. I wasn't aware this was possible. I will take a look, and report back soon :).

Comment: The suggestion made by @Botus works. I hooked into the global jQuery ajaxComplete handler which fires for all jQuery Ajax requests - whether made using our own functions or Kendo.

If not authenticated on the server, I just add a header to let the client know authentication is required (I can't set a status code as this will cause other issues) - and then do my redirect to the login page. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

For reference, someone from Telerik has provided a solution using just the DataSource. I haven't tested it, but I prefer the accepted answer above as it hooked into all Ajax on the site - not just ones that utilise the Kendo DataSource.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/global-error-handler-for-numerous-grids.aspx